# java split by bracket and keep the delmiter - RegEx

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to split the string using regex with closing bracket as a delimiter and have to keep the bracket..

```
i/p String: (GROUP=test1)(GROUP=test2)(GROUP=test3)(GROUP=test4)

needed o/p: 
(GROUP=test1)
(GROUP=test2)
(GROUP=test3)
(GROUP=test4)
```

I am using the java regex - "\([^)]*?\)" and it is throwing me the error..Below is the code I am using and when I try to get the group, its throwing the error..

```
    Pattern splitDelRegex = Pattern.compile("\\([^)]*?\\)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = splitDelRegex.matcher("(GROUP=test1)(GROUP=test2)    (GROUP=test3)(GROUP=test4)");
    List<String> matcherList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(regexMatcher.find()){
        String perm = regexMatcher.group(1);
        matcherList.add(perm);
    }
```

any help is appreciated..Thanks

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I am getting group(1) not found error:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply forgot to put capturing parentheses around the entire regex. You are not capturing anything at all.  Just change the regex to

```
Pattern splitDelRegex = Pattern.compile("(\\([^)]*?\\))");
                                         ^            ^
```

I tested this in Eclipse and got your desired output.

Comment: its working as expected Jim..thanks for ur help..:)

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
str.split(")")
```

That would return an array of strings which you would know are lacking the closing parentheses and so could add them back in afterwards. Thats seems much easier and less error prone to me.

Answer (score -1):

You could try changing this line :

```
String perm = regexMatcher.group(1);
```

To this :

```
String perm = regexMatcher.group();
```

So you read the last found group.

Comment: I tested this and it works. Not sure why i got downvoted. Same for matt´s answer

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you need to split the string at all. You can capture each of the bracketed groups with a regex.

Try this regex `(\\([a-zA-Z0-9=]*\\))`. I have a capturing group `()` that looks for text that starts with a literal `\\(`, contains `[a-zA-Z0-9=]` zero or many times `*` and ends with a literal `\\)`. This is a pretty loose regex, you could tighten up the match if the text inside the brackets will be predictable.

```
String input = "(GROUP=test1)(GROUP=test2)(GROUP=test3)(GROUP=test4)";
String regex = "(\\([a-zA-Z0-9=]*\\))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

while(matcher.find()) { // find the next match
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // print the match
}
```

Output:

```
(GROUP=test1)
(GROUP=test2)
(GROUP=test3)
(GROUP=test4)
```